# How to end main function from a custom library?

Tags: python, exit, exit-code, quit

I use a list of different python scripts for various functions. To help facilitate this, I've organized all of my reusable functions into custom libraries. However, I found that many of these functions will error out for strange reasons, some known and some unknown. I designed the below function to at least let me see the error message before throwing a giant traceback at me. I have the below command in one library:

```
FooBar = trace_check(lambda: Foo(bar))
```

This is the error catching function in a separate library:

```
def trace_check(func):
    try:
        return func()
    except:
        TracebackString = traceback.format_exc() ###This gets the traceback as a string.
        type, message, tracebacklocation = sys.exc_info() ###This gets the components, particularly the message.
        print "An error has occurred with the following error message:"
        print type    ###Example is IOError
        print message     ###The message associated with the error
        TracebackPrompt = ask("Do you want to see the entire traceback?") #Returns True/False value
        if TracebackPrompt:
            print TracebackString
        print 'Exiting Python Script' ###This shows me it gets to this point.
        sys.exit(0)  ###This is the problem
        print "Did it work?"    ###This statement does not print, so exit worked...
```

When trace_check runs and I get an error, the sys.exit only quits the function back out to main() instead of ending main. if I use os._exit() instead, the main() function ends correctly, but the program running the script also dies. One command is not strong enough and the other is overkill... what could I do instead to ensure the main() function ends?

Note: I tried putting the meat of my trace_check function into the first library, but the same thing happens with the library call ending but not the main().

tl;dr - Python: main() calls function in library that calls a second function in separate library. Second function has a sys.exit() command that only exits to main() instead of ending main(). os._exit() kills shell and is overkill (requires restarting shell TT^TT). Is there another way to end the main() from a function library?

Comment: why not throw a specialized exception that you capture on main() and return accordingly?

Comment: I think using any sort of exiting function is a sign of bad design.

Comment: What do you mean by "exists to main()"? That's not what `sys.exit` is supposed to do. Does `main` have a blanket `except` in it?

Answer (score 1):

To directly answer your question, if you want to handle [sys.exit()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit) calls from main, then you should catch the SystemExit exception that is raised by sys.exit().  The sample code below illustrates how to do that.

```
import sys


def func():
    sys.exit(1)


def main():
    try:
        func()
    except SystemExit:
        print 'Someone sys.exit()d'
    return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

However!  You should probably redesign your library.  Instead of calling sys.exit() when something unexpected happens, you should raise an Exception.  Having a library abruptly exit the interpreter is bad design.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting this off by throwing an exception:

```
class ExitFromMain(Exception):
    pass   

def trace_check(func):
    try:
        # try stuff
    except:
        # traceback stuff you had
        raise ExitFromMain()

def main():
    try:
        # Stuff
        trace_check()
        # More stuff that will not run if the exception is thrown
    except ExitFromMain:
        print "I hit my excception to flag a quit from this function"
        sys.exit(0)
```